# How can I find out what triggered the TRACKER_ID rule in spamassassin?

Tags: email, error-reporting, spamassassin, spam-prevention

I recently received an email from my girlfriend that spamassassin marked as spam, mostly because spamassassin detected a tracker ID... except there wasn't one.  I'd like to know what triggered it, so that I can report a sensible bug.

Comment: John - why do you think is this off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about looking at the rule in question? Google says this:

> /^[a-z0-9]{6,24}[-_a-z0-9]{12,36}[a-z0-9]{6,24}\s*\z/is
>
> ...which in its current form will hit (some, depending on hyphenation) words
> with 24 or more characters.  So maybe someone who is familiar with tracker IDs
> can adjust the regexp so that large words (say 30 characters?) won't get hit.

URL: https://issues.apache.org/SpamAssassin/show_bug.cgi?id=2307

That's 2005, so it might have changed.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, you can see the TRACKER_ID rule as distributed in SpamAssassin 3.2.5 at http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JMASON/Mail-SpamAssassin-3.2.5/rules/20_body_tests.cf